# Print all php variables names using command-line

Tags: php, shell, variables

I have numerous variables within different php files, and I just want to list them in my terminal.

I guess the command begins with 'cat file.php file2.php' and ends with '| sort | uniq' but I failed finding a pattern that matches a variable, and I have no idea how to cut them from the rest of the line..

Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: google "php cross reference"

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
egrep -o '\$\w+' *.php | sort -u
```

Variables start with `$` and are followed by alphanumeric charaters.

Comment: Thanks so much, and I will pay more attention to the tags I set, next time :)